# Trying to find a index of a list based off a certian string value. index() doesn't seem to be doing the trick

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently working on a assignment that requires me to take in a .csv value and format it to a specific criteria. I also not allowed to use any python libraries that do this, my professor also doesn't want us to hard code a solution based off of file names. This is the third assignment of this category and because of how the .csv's are formatted in this particular assignment I am no longer able to retrieve the values of interest by indexing at specific location in the list that I made. Below I will add the code I had previously and the code that was attempting to use .index as well as the first part of the list that I have set up.

Original solution:

```
for line in csvReaderR:
    stripper = line.strip("\n")
    splitter = stripper.split(",")
    if splitter[2] == projection_year:
        data_list.append(splitter)

for popProjection in data_list:
    try:
        name = popProjection[0]
        population = popProjection[4]
    except IndexError:
        population = popProjection[3]
```

New solution:

```
if splitter.index("year") == projection_year:
    data_list.append(splitter)
for popProjection in data_list:
    name = popProjection.index("State")
    population = popProjection.index("Projected populations")
```

the list is below I have it structured in a way that each individual indices is a column and if i were to index it at 1 in this particular case it would take Year and everything below. The problem is that the indexes change depending upon the .csv file and we are not allowed to hard code a solution in.

```
['State', 'Year', 'Projected Populations']
['Alabama', '2004', '4513207']
['Alabama', '2005', '4527166']
['Alabama', '2006', '4541263']
['Alabama', '2007', '4555152']
['Alabama', '2008', '4568983']
['Alabama', '2009', '4582698']
```

Comment: what you want is to use namedtuple https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

docs for it even have CSV example

Comment: It appears that the example shown in this documentation uses the csv library. for this assignment I am unable to use any modules so I had to create a list to hold in all of the data, Im not quite sure this function would work with a list in this circumstance.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to acheive. Could you make a couple of simple examples?